# joomla 3 custom module class name

Tags: module, joomla3.1

Running Joomla 3.1.5

I created a very simple module and I can't find anywhere in the module options where to add a class name.  This was easy in earlier versions of Joomla; there was a "Menu Class Suffix" field under "ADVANCED OPTIONS."

How do I add a class name to my custom module?  Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your manifest (mod_yourmodule.xml) add the following field inside the respective fieldset

```
<field name="moduleclass_sfx"
       type="text"
       label="COM_MODULES_FIELD_MODULECLASS_SFX_LABEL"
       description="COM_MODULES_FIELD_MODULECLASS_SFX_DESC"/>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I added this in my module XML settings file inside <config><fields name="params"><fieldset name="basic"> and in my module settings inside Joomla, it added a new category in the "Options" tab called "Basic Options" and an inside option labeled "Module Class Suffix."  Thanks for the solution; much appreciated.